# Updating a gui after getting new data from http request

Tags: java, user-interface, http-request

I want to build a little Tool for monitoring my favorite Let's Player Gronkh.

What i got so far:

A main class:

```
public class mainClass {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        // final String url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/gronkh/";

        // final workerClass w = new workerClass(url);
        gronkhGui.launch();

        // String URL = "http://eu.battle.net/api/d3/profile/tortoc-2624/";
        // final String bNetString = d3AccInfo.request.sendGet(URL);
        // System.out.println(bNetString);

    }
}
```

A Gui:

```
public class gronkhGui extends JFrame {

    public gronkhGui() {
        getContentPane().setLayout(
                new FormLayout(new ColumnSpec[] {
                        FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_COLSPEC,
                        FormFactory.DEFAULT_COLSPEC,
                        FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_COLSPEC,
                        FormFactory.DEFAULT_COLSPEC,
                        FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_COLSPEC,
                        FormFactory.DEFAULT_COLSPEC, }, new RowSpec[] {
                        FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_ROWSPEC,
                        FormFactory.DEFAULT_ROWSPEC,
                        FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_ROWSPEC,
                        FormFactory.DEFAULT_ROWSPEC,
                        FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_ROWSPEC,
                        FormFactory.DEFAULT_ROWSPEC,
                        FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_ROWSPEC,
                        FormFactory.DEFAULT_ROWSPEC,
                        FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_ROWSPEC,
                        FormFactory.DEFAULT_ROWSPEC,
                        FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_ROWSPEC,
                        FormFactory.DEFAULT_ROWSPEC,
                        FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_ROWSPEC,
                        FormFactory.DEFAULT_ROWSPEC,
                        FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_ROWSPEC,
                        FormFactory.DEFAULT_ROWSPEC,
                        FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_ROWSPEC,
                        FormFactory.DEFAULT_ROWSPEC, }));

        final JLabel textLabel = new JLabel("Gronkh ist: ");
        textLabel.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        getContentPane().add(textLabel, "6, 2");

        final JLabel stateLabel = new JLabel("");
        stateLabel.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        getContentPane().add(stateLabel, "6, 6");

        final JLabel gameLabel = new JLabel("");
        getContentPane().add(gameLabel, "6, 10");

        final JLabel gameLabelText = new JLabel("");
        getContentPane().add(gameLabelText, "6, 12");

        final JLabel viewerLabel = new JLabel("");
        getContentPane().add(viewerLabel, "6, 16");

        final JLabel viewerLabelText = new JLabel("");
        getContentPane().add(viewerLabelText, "6, 18");

        final String url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/gronkh/";

        final workerClass w = new workerClass(url);
        if (w.state.equals("OFFLINE")) {
            stateLabel.setText(w.state);
            gameLabel.setText("");
            gameLabelText.setText("");
            viewerLabel.setText("");
            viewerLabelText.setText("");
            getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
        } else {
            stateLabel.setText(w.state);
            gameLabel.setText("Gronkh spielt:");
            gameLabelText.setText(w.game);
            viewerLabel.setText("Zuschauer:");
            viewerLabelText.setText(w.viewers);
            getContentPane().setBackground(Color.green);
        }
    }

    public static void launch() {
        final gronkhGui gui = new gronkhGui();
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setBounds(400, 200, 170, 304);
    }

}
```

A worker Class:

```
public class workerClass {

    public String state;
    public String game;
    public String viewers;
    public String name;

    public workerClass(final String url) {
        String request = "";

        try {
            request = gronkhInfo.request.sendGet(url);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (!request.contains("\"stream\":null")) {
            this.state = "ONLINE";
            this.game = request.substring(request.indexOf("game\" : \"") + 8,
                    request.indexOf("\",\"viewers"));
            this.viewers = request.substring(
                    request.indexOf("viewers\": ") + 10,
                    request.indexOf(",\"created_at"));
            this.name = request.substring(
                    request.indexOf("display_name\": \"") + 16,
                    request.indexOf("\",\"game"));

        } else {
            this.state = "OFFLINE";
        }
    }
}
```

A request class:

```
public class request {
    public final static String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    public static String sendGet(final String url) throws Exception {

        final URL obj = new URL(url);
        final HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        final StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        final String respo = response.toString();
        return respo;

    }
}
```

What i now want to do is updating the Gui for example every 30 seconds.
This means i have to do a http request again and then renew the gui.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could define workerClass as Runnable thread and you could run it every 30 secs using ScheduledThreadPool executor like:

```
ScheduledExecutorService sevice = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
sevice.schedule(new workerClass(), 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

And then you could notify GUI with say new string created of workerClass.

Comment: i have inserted the code and made my class absract and implemented Runnable. 
Now the "new workerClass()" out of you code shows an error saying: "Cannot instantiate the type workerClass"

How can i notify the gui?